# How to configure apache to use ipv6 for subdomains

Tags: apache, subdomain, ipv6

I have just setup a website using a domain like domain.com. And then setup another website sub.domain.com.
Now both of them can be visited via ipv4. And then I added the ipv6 address[a:b::c:d]. However, when I restarted httpd service, the following message appeared:

> [warn] VirtualHost a:b::c:d:80 overlaps with VirtualHost a:b::c:d:80,
>   the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost
>   directive.

I can now only visit domain.com via ipv6, not sub.domain.com. But, somehow, I can visit domain.com/sub via ipv6. I seems that ipv6 address cannot be treated like ipv4 address in apache. I am wondering how could I configure the apache to behave as what I wish.

I have the following lines in my httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:80
Listen [a:b::c:d]:80

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName domain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost [a:b::c:d]:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName domain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/ipv6_error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/logs/ipv6_access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/sub_error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/logs/sub_access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost [a:b::c:d]:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/sub6_error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/logs/sub6_access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Very interesting question, but perhaps more suited for serverfault.com?

Comment: Perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jeremy Visser mentioned, I searched the config file and found the following line:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
```

It seems that this is the problem. Then I added this line:

```
NameVirtualHost [a:b::c:d]:80
```

The problem was settled!